# How not to roll back previous methods persist data?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpa-2.1

My DAO interface is simple:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Transactional
public interface TTestDao {

    @Transactional()
    public void first();

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void second() ;

}
```

ad impl methods:

```
@Override
public void first() {
          entityManager.persist(new TableTest1().setName("data1"));
          this.second();      
}

public void second() {
     entityManager.persist(new TableTest1().setName("data2"));
     throw new RuntimeException(); // it roll backs data2 and data1
}
```

First method invokes second method. Error occurs in second method.

At the moment, if I call `first()`,  all  persisted information will be rolled back. But why does this happen? `second()` method is in a new transaction, and I need to keep the first method's data in the db.

In the other words, I need to always persist the first method's data, but roll back only second methods data.  I want to write data1 always.

Do I have anything wrong?

I have such a db configuration in SPRING:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"
    p:username="dev" p:password="****" >
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="ge.ddrc.transport.persistance.entity">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My App is running in tomcat (if it makes any sences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StijnGeukens is close.  Spring does in fact use proxies to handle the transactions, and by [default](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) calling one transactional method from within another would not result in a new transaction being created.  However, in this case propogation is being specifically set to explicitly [require a new](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) transaction being created.  There should be 2 transactions being created:

```
T1: create
    T2: create
    Exception occurs here
    T2: commit
T1: commit
```

As you can see, the exception is occurring before either transaction reaches its commit point.  Since it isn't handled in `First`, execution wouldn't ever reach the commit point for `T1`.  That would result in the top-level transaction being rolled back.

**However, it is possible that you could handle the exception in `First` and it still wouldn't work.**  From the docs I linked to above:

```
Note: Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to JtaTransactionManager, which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard J2EE).
```

So your `propagation=REQUIRES_NEW` is likely not actually doing what it says it does because it doesn't like your `TransactionManager`.  Welcome to Spring.

**Update**
From the [JpaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) docs:

> On JDBC 3.0, this transaction manager supports nested transactions via
>   JDBC 3.0 Savepoints. The
>   `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(boolean)
>   "nestedTransactionAllowed"` flag defaults to "false", though, as
>   nested transactions will just apply to the JDBC Connection, not to the
>   JPA EntityManager and its cached objects. You can manually set the
>   flag to "true" if you want to use nested transactions for JDBC access
>   code which participates in JPA transactions (provided that your JDBC
>   driver supports Savepoints). Note that JPA itself does not support
>   nested transactions! Hence, do not expect JPA access code to
>   semantically participate in a nested transaction.

This is very confusing but I think what it's saying is that if you set the flag mentioned, you will be able to use nested transactions, implemented using a feature of JDBC 3.0.  So make sure that your driver meets that specification.

Comment: Thank u for your good and awesome answer! and I will give you +1 votes! I have updated my question. As I understand I should use JTA Transaction Manager in order to solve my problem. is it true? p.s what is best practice, which transaction manager is the best in spring? how to choose? Also I use aspectj in db config, is it also good practice? I'm new in spring. thanks again!

Comment: @grep see my update.  It seems like you can still use the same transaction manager as long as you set the appropriate flag.  As far as your `tx:annotation-driven mode` is concerned, ASPECTJ seems to be the appropriate choice according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232624/nested-transaction-on-spring).

Comment: At the moment I use JpaTranasctionManager in XML configuration. And in java, I use EntityManager in order to work with db. where should I declare AbstractPlatformTransactionManager? Should I change EntityManager to AbstractPlatformTransaction Manager? I was unable to find samples in network...

Answer (score 1):

There is still an exception thrown from the second method. So, yes, you created 2 transactions but both will be rolled back because of the same exception. If you do not want to roll back the first method then you will have to surround the call to the second method with a try catch (so that no exception is thrown to the Transactional pointcut).

In general however it is not a good idea to call one transaction from another since it will not be clear  what the scope of a transaction is (this is not visible on the interface). So, if possible, better to call the 2 methods separately from your front end (or wherever from) and ignore any exception from the second method there.

**UPDATE**

The problem in your case however is something completely different. Spring transactions use proxies that handle the transaction (and exceptions). Since you call second() from first() you are completely bypassing the proxy so no new transaction is never created.

Comment: try {this.second();} catch () - when I do that, it saves all method data - data1 and data2 in tables. I want to keep only data1.

Comment: Try this more realistic use case: make the DB column name not nullable and then don't set a name when persisting TableTest1. Also consider the second paragraph in my post.

Comment: try catch  does not solves the problem. this is not correct one.

Comment: My answer (and the one from jmvivo) was correct but your problem has a different cause (see my update).

Comment: Thank u Stijn. Do u wanted to write   "never created" instead of "ever created". If spring will creates new transaction, everything will  be ok does not it?.. is there any spring solution?...

Comment: BTW, interesting read: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html#N10226

Comment: @StijnGeukens that IBM doc you linked to specifically confirms that a calling one `@Transactional` method with `propogation=REQUIRES_NEW` from within another will result in a new transaction being created and the current transaction suspended.

Comment: Actually, it does not state that both methods are in the same class. Put method1 & method2 in 2 different DAO's, inject the second DAO in the first and see if it works then.

Comment: I will test and I will give you +1 votes. thank you, I will check this :)

Comment: @StijnGeukens [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232624/nested-transaction-on-spring) question does specifically address them being in the same class.  OP's updated configuration details show that it is properly configured for AspectJ-style weaving rather than runtime proxy-based transactions.

Answer (score 0):

try to catch `second` exception on `first`:

```
@Override
public void first() {
      entityManager.persist(new TableTest1().setName("data1"));
      try {
         this.second();      
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // Do nothing
      }
}

public void second() {
      entityManager.persist(new TableTest1().setName("data2"));
     throw new RuntimeException(); // it roll backs data2
}
```

Comment: No. it odes not roll backs "data2".  I want only to save first() method data. but it saves all method data.

Comment: try {this.second();} catch () - when I do that, it saves all method data - data1 and data2 in tables. I want to keep only data1.